Disabling Legacy Google FCM API - will key be preserved?
I just implemented Google FCM HTTP v1 API on my sever and it sems to be working. Now I need to disable Legacy FCM APIs. When I try to do it, I get a warning that all resouces associated with this API will be deallocated soon, etc. Does it mean that the key associated with this API will be deallocated too, and if I will want to re-enable it (in case I did something wrong with the new API), will the key be lost forever and I will not be able to use the old API, or the key will stay and I can re-enable it safely if I need to?
